Size Limit Exceeded Error in IBM ILOG CPLEX
I'm working on a constrained scheduling problem using IBM ILOG CPLEX. Despite having no syntax errors in my code, I keep encountering a "Size Limit Exceeded" error, which prevents the code from running successfully.
Here's a brief overview of my problem setup:
I'm scheduling a set of tasks with various constraints (e.g., resource limitations, task dependencies).
I've defined the variables, objective function, and constraints correctly as per the CPLEX documentation.
The problem size is substantial but not unreasonably large for CPLEX to handle, to the best of my knowledge.
I tried to make the arrangements I could within my CPLEX knowledge, but I could not obtain any findings.
Here is the code;
**
int n=...;
 int m=...;  //resources
 range i=0..n-1;
 range j=0..n-1;
 range t=0..n-1;
 range k=0..m-1;
 range z=0..n-1;
 
 int B[k]= ...; //Capacities
 int p[i]= ...; //activity duratio
 int ES[i]=...;
 int LS[i]=...;
 int b[i][k]=...;
 range A=0..n-1; //activities
 range R=0..m-1; //Resources
 range A_plus1 = 0..n-1; // Include n+1 in the range 
 range H= 0..LS[n-1]; //Time horizon
tuple MyTuple { 
    int i; 
    int j; 
} 
{MyTuple} E = ...; // Use your actual data here 
// int V=asSet(1..n);
 dvar boolean x[i][t];
 
 minimize sum(i in 0..n-1) 
           sum(t in ES[i]..LS[i]) t*x[n-1][t];
 subject to 
{
forall(e in E)  
        sum(t in ES[e.j]..LS[e.j])t*x[e.j][t]>= sum(t in ES[e.i]..LS[e.i])t*x[e.i][t]+p[e.i];
 forall(t in H, k in R) 
        sum(i in 0..n-1) 
            b[i][k] * sum(z in maxl(ES[i],t - p[i] + 1) .. minl(LS[i], t))
            x[i][z] <= B[k];
             
forall(i in A_plus1) 
      sum(t in ES[i]..LS[i])x[i][t]==1;
       
 x[0][0]==1;
 //forall(i in A union {n+1})
      //forall(t in {ES[i],LS[i]})               
forall(i in A_plus1)
      forall(t in H : !(t in {ES[i], LS[i]}))
          x[i][t]==0;
           
forall(i in A_plus1) 
      forall(t in H : (t >= ES[i] && t<= LS[i]))  
          x[i][t] == 1; 
}

**
Here is the dat file I'm using,
n = 32;

m = 4;
 
Activity durations

p = [0, 6, 1, 4, 5, 7, 3, 5, 6, 9, 9, 5, 7, 4, 10, 10, 5, 10, 6, 10, 7, 9, 10, 1, 6, 6, 9, 4, 4, 7, 1,0 ];
 
Resource availability

B = [10, 10, 10, 10];
 
Resource requirements

b = [

[0, 0, 0, 0],

    [1, 1, 1,0],

    [6,0, 2, 1],

    [0,1, 4,3],

    [2, 6, 2, 0],

    [5, 3, 0, 5],

    [6, 4, 4, 0],

    [0, 6, 5, 2],

    [2, 6, 0, 5],

    [6, 6, 6, 0],

    [4, 0, 6, 5],

    [4, 5, 4, 0],

    [2, 3, 0, 3],

    [0, 3, 2, 3],

    [5, 3, 4, 0],

    [2, 5, 4, 0],

    [5, 4, 3, 0],

    [4, 0, 4, 3],

    [7, 1, 0, 4],

    [0, 3, 4, 7],

    [7, 4, 4, 0],

    [0, 4, 6, 7],

    [2, 7, 4, 0],

    [0, 7, 5, 1],

    [2, 0, 4, 3],

    [8, 0, 4, 5],

    [0, 2, 3, 5],

    [2, 6, 3, 0],

    [3, 0, 4, 7],

    [1, 0, 7, 3],

    [6, 2, 5, 0],

    [0, 0, 0, 0]
];

Include data for all activities and resources here
 
Precedence constraints

E = {

    <0, 2>,<0, 4>, <0, 5>, <0, 6>, <0, 7>,<0,16>, <0, 17>, <0, 18>, <0, 19>, <0, 20>, <0, 21>, <0, 22>, <0, 23>, <0, 24>, <0, 25>, <0, 26>, <0, 27>, <0, 28>, <0, 29>, <0, 30>, <0, 31>,

    <1, 14>, <1, 2>,

    <2, 8>, <2, 7>,

    <3, 13>, <3, 12>,

    <4, 11>, <4, 7>,

    <5, 10>,

    <6, 9>,

    <7, 31>,

    <8, 31>,

    <9, 31>,

    <10, 31>,

    <11, 31>,

    <12, 31>,

    <13, 31>,

    <14, 31>,

    <15, 31>,

    <16, 31>,

    <17, 31>,

    <18, 31>,

    <19, 31>,

    <20, 31>,

    <21, 31>,

    <22, 31>,

    <23, 31>,

    <24, 31>,

    <25, 31>,

    <26, 31>,

    <27, 31>,

    <28, 31>,

    <29, 31>,

    <30, 31>,
    


};

  Earliest start times
ES = [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 3, 7, 5, 10, 10, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0];
 
Latest start times
LS = [0, 0, 10, 6, 8, 8, 8, 15, 14, 11, 11, 15, 13, 16, 10, 10, 15, 10, 0, 10, 13, 11, 10, 10, 19, 14, 14, 11, 16, 16, 19, 20];


The free community CPLEX edition is limited with regards to problem size, as said in https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-free-ibm-cplex-alex-fleischer/
With the watsonx / WML service you have some free time whatever the size of the model.
You can also move to a non limited version
https://www.ibm.com/products/ilog-cplex-optimization-studio/pricing

If you run this version, you will see that your model is not feasible.
Then if you name your constraints in order to see some relaxations:
 subject to 
{
forall(e in E)  
        ct1:sum(t in ES[e.j]..LS[e.j])t*x[e.j][t]>= sum(t in ES[e.i]..LS[e.i])t*x[e.i][t]+p[e.i];
 forall(t in H, k in R) 
        ct2:sum(i in 0..n-1) 
            b[i][k] * sum(z in maxl(ES[i],t - p[i] + 1) .. minl(LS[i], t))
            x[i][z] <= B[k];
             
forall(i in A_plus1) 
      ct3:sum(t in ES[i]..LS[i])x[i][t]==1;
       
 x[0][0]==1;
 //forall(i in A union {n+1})
      //forall(t in {ES[i],LS[i]})               
forall(i in A_plus1)
      forall(t in H : !(t in {ES[i], LS[i]}))
          ct4:x[i][t]==0;
           
forall(i in A_plus1) 
      forall(t in H : (t >= ES[i] && t<= LS[i]))  
          ct5:x[i][t] == 1; 
}

You will see some conflict and relaxation
So your issue is indeed that you use the community edition


Our "n" value is 32, which means that even in all variations, our number of variables is at maximum six hundred. In the version I use, CPLEX should not exceed the 1000 variable limit.

32 Times 32 , I get 1024 which is bigger than 1000

Is the only reason for the type of error I get is the sizing problem, I mean, isn't it possible that this is caused by another error in my code? Could it be that my code is infeasible or is caused by another error?
I'm asking this because this is part of a term project, so it's unlikely there will be errors in sizing.

Added the dat file, In case you want to examine.

Try with a smaller problem instance. That should prove whether your problem is correctly structured and you can check the variable and constraint counts match what you expect.

Indeed, with the full version you do not get any more this error message about the model being too big

We tried it in a small instance, but OPL cannot extract expression: t*x[e.j][t],
I understand what you mean, we need to do relaxation right now, with community edition, our code is infeasible, right now. @AlexFleischer
